# How to add a cck email field as default value in webform

Tags: entities, webforms, emails

I have a content profile type with a cck email field (this is not the user email and so is not the author's email field). I would like guests to be able to send a contact form (webform) to the email address in the cck mail field.

I have the field displayed via views in a panel so I can change the link to output the url to include the email address and use %get in the webform but that is obviously not the way to go as it exposes the email address.

So can it be done using %post or php in the webform?

Using D6 & webform 3

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the [Email Field](http://drupal.org/project/email) module then it is possible.

In your view choose your email field , on Format option choose the *Email contact form* option.  It won't expose the email.